# How to easily change Automatic Property to Full Property?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, automatic-properties

I have a *lot* of properties that were originally implemented using automatic properties. Is there an easy way to change automatic properties to fully implemented properties without having to basically delete the properties and start over? In VB, I believe this is possible with a certain combination of cursor position (right in front of the Get?) and a couple of tabs. Is this possible in C#?

Comment: I don't suppose you're using ReSharper?

Comment: I am not using ReSharper, unfortunately.

Comment: This is more a question regarding the editor you use. What editor do you use?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio just type `propfull` then tab twice, see this link for other good code [snippets](http://www.dotnetperls.com/snippet)

Comment: I knew about this... Due to time constraints I will have to do this anyways, it seems. I was more looking for something that might quickly "reformat" my properties for me.